# Which web feed type should I use?

Tags: rss, feed, atom-feed

I am plan to code a blog, and I have never wrote feed before, I heard some feed types before but I have no idea of which is better or should I support all feeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what you choose between RSS and Atom, do not support both. There is no decent parser out there which doesn't support both, so it's useless to support both.

Make sure you **pick one and do it well**! USe the [feed validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/).

I would go for Atom, because the spec is generally a lot clearer, but again, in the end, it's up to you.

Also, please make sure you support [PubSuhHubbub](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/) for these feeds, this will reduce polling on your end and it's a good thing.